# HTTP redirect to HTTPS and back again with Virtual Host

Tags: apache, http, https, virtualhost

It was simple enough to configure my Virtual Host to redirect to HTTPS from HTTP when accessing a page in a certain directory. What doesn't seem to be so simple is going beach to HTTP after you leave that directory and go to pages outside it. Is that even possible?

Here is my Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/pokerprimacy/httpdocs"
    ServerName pokerprimacy.local
    ServerAlias www.pokerprimacy.local
    <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/pokerprimacy/httpdocs>
       AllowOverride All
       Allow from All
    </Directory>
     Redirect /members https://pokerprimacy.local/members
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/pokerprimacy/httpdocs"
    ServerName pokerprimacy.local
    ServerAlias www.pokerprimacy.local
    <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/pokerprimacy/httpdocs>
       AllowOverride All
       Allow from All
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl.key/server.key 
</VirtualHost>
```

You can see this is being done locally. So, if I start on the home page at /, it is using HTTP. If I then go to /members/login, it uses HTTPS; as it should. But, from there, if I go back to the home page, it is still using HTTPS. Is there a way to toggle between HTTP and HTTPS only when I'm at a page in the members directory?